# .dockerignore problems : ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: manifest for php:5-apache-dev not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: docker

i am currently developing an web application running in a Docker-Container.
It ran just fine for the past months until I made a backup before reinstalling docker.
Other projects work just fine like they did. However, this one does not. If i try to build the container in a docker-compose file it gets stuck at building web with the error message:
"Step 1/2 : FROM php:5-apache-dev
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: manifest for php:5-apache-dev not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"

version: '3.3'
services:

```
  web:
   build: ./php 
   depends_on:
     - mariadb
   environment:
     - ALLOW_OVERRIDE=true
   ports:
     - "80:80"
   links:
     - mariadb
     - influxdb
   volumes:
     - ./:/var/www/html/
```

So i tried to build the container on its own with

```
docker build ./php
```

which stated: "Sending build context to Docker daemon xyzGB"
This stops at 3.59Gb and then throws the same error message.

I then created a .dockerignore

Now it just throws the Error right away:

```
Step 1/2 : FROM php:5-apache-dev
manifest for php:5-apache-dev not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

files are organizd as such:

- project(folder)

  - docker-compose.yml
  - .dockerignore
  - php(folder)

    - InfluxDB
    - Dockerfile
    - .dockerignore (tried to put it here aswell)

Also with every try my harddrive lost extreme amounts of clear storage. I found out that all went to the Docker.raw file in
/Users/Me/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data

I had to delete this file in the process several times as it seemed not to make any damage and there were no new images created that I could've deleted in "docker images"

Sorry if this is a very basic mistake and to waste your time. I am a beginner and have no clue what else to try...
Thanks a lot!